# What does **___________ mean in /etc/shadow?

Tags: password, shadow

When I look at /etc/shadow I see several entries that look like this:

`username:**___________:::::::`

What does the "**___________" mean? That is where I should see the password hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A password field that starts with `*` means the corresponding user is not allowed to login.  This is generally used for system accounts, such as `mysql`, `mail`, `apache`, etc.

However, if the entry is literally ending with `:::::::`, this means the corresponding user is a NIS / NIS+ account.